# How to Prevent Overlapping of Subplots in Python?

Tags: python, subplot

I am plotting various parameters in three different subplots. My second and third subplots are overlapping and I'm not understanding what is causing it. I have specified ax1, ax2, and ax3 and I'm thinking the issue may be from fig.add_subplot() but I'm not sure how to fix it. See my code below for reference. I only included the portions for the set up of the figure and the final plot since all three plots are generated practically in the same manner. I also included an image of what the plot is looking like that I wish to fix.

[image]

```
# Convert dataframe to 2D maps
lon_grid, lat_grid = np.meshgrid(data.lon.unique(), data.lat.unique())
L_grid = data.L.values.reshape(len(data.lat.unique()), len(data.lon.unique()))
Lam_grid = data.lam.values.reshape(len(data.lat.unique()), len(data.lon.unique()))
R_grid = data.R2.values.reshape(len(data.lat.unique()), len(data.lon.unique()))

# Make figures
fig = plt.figure(figsize= (10, 30), facecolor='white')
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2,projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,3,projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    
# Draw coastlines, states and countries for plot 3
ax3.coastlines()
ax3.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS)
ax3.add_feature(cfeature.STATES)
 
# Draw parallels and meridians for plot 3
parallels = np.arange(-90,91,30)
meridians = np.arange(-180,181,60)
gl = ax3.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=False,
                  linewidth=2, color='gray', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--')
gl.xlocator = mticker.FixedLocator(meridians)
gl.ylocator = mticker.FixedLocator(parallels)
    
ax3.set_xticks(np.arange(-180,181,30), crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax3.set_yticks(parallels, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
lon_formatter = LongitudeFormatter(zero_direction_label=True)
lat_formatter = LatitudeFormatter()
ax3.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lon_formatter)
ax3.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lat_formatter)
    
# Add Longitude wrap-around points at 0/360 for plot 3
cyclic_R_grid, cyclic_lons = cutil.add_cyclic_point(R_grid, coord=data.lon.unique())
c3 = ax3.contourf(cyclic_lons, data.lat.unique(), cyclic_R_grid, alpha = 1.0,
                transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), levels = np.arange(0,100), \
                vmin = 0.0, vmax = 100.0)  

# Overplot rigidity
c3_ = ax3.imshow(np.flip(R_grid, axis=1), interpolation = 'gaussian', alpha = 0.6, extent = (-180,180,-90,90))

cbar = plt.colorbar(c3, ax=ax3, fraction=0.025)
cbar.set_label('R')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding your subplots wrong. `fig.add_subplot` expects `n_rows`,`n_cols`, `index` in that order. So the correct definition would be

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize= (10, 30), facecolor='white')
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,1,projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,2,projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,3,projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```